# iPhone device token not match with download times

Tags: iphone, push-notification, devicetoken

I have configured the iPhone App to submit device token to the database table when user install it.

After checked the iPhone App download time at itunesconnect.apple.com > Sales and Trends, I found that it have 4xxx download time. However, I checked the database, it only have 2xxx device token record.

Did anyone know why the figure is not match?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something may have gone wrong at your server, it may have been down, or the users of your app may not have been connected to the internet. Do a few tests yourself, try without internet connection and see what you get, and so on.

If these tokens are connected to push-notifications (which is really the only reason you should send them and store them on a server), the user may have declined the use of push-notifications in your app.